# SVN: Can I commit files that I manually added to a directory of an svn:external?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have a repository R, in which I have an svn:externals entry to repository X under directory `vendors/x`. I now added a file manually at `vendors/x/subdir/myfile`. The subdir was already provided by repository X.

What I want to do is commit myfile into my repository R. Can that be done?

I am using the SVN CLI utilities 1.6.12 on Mac OS X 10.6, just for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't add a file to R if the file is inside of X. X is a completely separate working directory to R.

You can commit the file into X, if you have commit rights, or you can move it into a non-external folder of R.